# Tensorflow/Keras - loading dataset in batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, dataset

I'm currently using Keras with Tensorflow backend to train a sequential model. The problem is, that my dataset is pretty large - about 64 thousand images (just under 16GB) for training. Since I have access to a workstation with quite a bit of RAM I'm able to load everything in the memory. However when I try to train the model with `model.fit()` I'm getting the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.
```

From what I read, the problem should be, that the data cannot be loaded into the GPUs (even though I have four RTX 3080s, 10GB memory). I'm not sure if the issue could lie somewhere else.

In any case, what I was trying to do is, to load the dataset in batches and then train only on parts of the dataset, using the `ImageDataGenerator` from Keras. However for my application it is important to load the data in a certain way.

My current folder structure looks like this:

```
training
        -video_1
               -frame_0000.tiff
               -frame_0001.tiff
               ...
               -frame_nnnn.tiff
        -video_2
               -...
        ...
        -video_n
```

Where every video has a different number of frames. It is important to load just the images from a single video folder and then do some preprocessing, namely convert them into sequences, consisting of 10 frames each. Alternatively I can use a batch size of 10 and load that much from the hard drive. However, it is important, that no sequence contains images, which are not from the same video. I haven't found a way to do this yet, so I wanted to ask if it is possible?

Additionally I would've liked to save model checkpoints from every model, since I need it for some additional evaluation for my thesis. In this relation, I wanted to know whether a single epoch would still mean, that the model is trained on all images?

Cheers